# Fluid combination lock resetting, forgot to turn the resetting knob back

Tags: lock

Out of the box, tried to reset the combination, forgot the step after setting the new number, where we turn the knob back, I forgot to turn the knob back, locked it. now it wont open with neither the original 0000 or the number that I though I set.

Since it was not turned back, then the new number should have not been set and 0000 should have opened it.

Any hints on how to open it without having to cut the cable?

Comment: A four digit number lock is "just" 1.5h worth of trying (actually 0 to 3h, assuming you can check one combination per second). That's doable. Whatever combination has actually been set, you can find it. However, I don't know how the mechanics of your lock works, so it may be possible that the mechanism is so thoroughly jammed that forceful methods are indeed the only way to open the lock.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this lock.  Are you confident that any number is locked in?  Or is it free to float internally ?   I'd suggest also contacting the manufacturer for their guidance.

Comment: After some jiggling it opened , was lucky , it was not locked only jammed. But wonder about any model,not having the combinationset yet and having moved the numbers after putting the two pars together, I guess it never gets locked unless the knob to set the combination is rotated back to its original position